# Localizing a long list of descriptions

Tags: c#

I've got a class with dozen of rows of type Sentence1, Sentence2 and so on. They contain a descriptive part which I want to localize. Is my solution correct (I mean not only work, but do you see any code smell).

```
[Serializable]
public class ResultType : ISerializable, IEquatable<ResultType>
{
    public int IDResultType { get; set; }
    public string ResultName { get; set; }
    public string ResultSymbol { get; set; }
    public bool IsTeam { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }

public static ResultType Sentence1 = new ResultType(1, Resource.Sentence1, "FT1");

public static ResultType Sentence2 = new ResultType(2, Resource.Sentence2, "FT2");

public static ResultType Sentence3 = new ResultType(3, Resource.Sentence3, "FT3");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawbacks:

- (If immutable.) Language is choosen at startup and can't be changed later.
- (If mutable.) Encapsulation is broken, anyone can change static instances and their properties.
- Language choice is unpredictable. When static instances are constructed this way, runtime can choose to call constructors of static fields before you set the language. (Can be fixed by adding explicit static constructor.)

In a simple application, it may be enough. In a more complex application, I'd rather add static properties. If garbage becomes an issue, values can be cached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot fully understand it. What is referred to the adjective mutable?

Comment: See [Immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). `ResultType` can be changed externally by any code, static fields of it can be changed too.

Comment: ah, you mean the whole class ResultType could be declared immutable?

Comment: If you aren't going to change instances, you can make the class immutable. The second of the listed issues will be fixed. Also, if you're going to use only the instances from the static fields/properties, you can make constructor private.